# At which pressure does a liquid fueled rocket start producing supersonic flow?

Tags: liquid-fuel, nozzle

In a compressed-tank LOX+ethanol (or similar liquid fuel) rocket:

How much should the tank or combustion chamber pressure (which should be the same) be to have a significant exhaust velocity increase due to combustion and for the de-laval nozzle to work as expected (high temperature high pressure-subsonic flow to lower temperature lower pressure supersonic flow)

Comment: @OrganicMarble Which is one of the top destructive rules of the SE.

Comment: @OrganicMarble its just an example, i am not asking whether the rocket will work or not, its just about the pressure ratio at which a de Laval nozzle starts working as expected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The critical pressure ratio for a de Laval nozzle is

$$\left(\frac{P_0}{P_{atm}}\right)_{crit} = \left(\frac{\gamma+1}{2}\right)^{{\gamma}/({\gamma-1})}$$

Where

- $P_0$ = stagnation pressure in chamber
- $P_{atm}$ = atmospheric (back) pressure
- $\gamma$ = ratio of specific heats for the gas

$(P_0 / P_{atm})$ must exceed this critical value  in order for a de Laval nozzle to achieve supersonic exhaust velocity.

Reference: [Sonic Flow Through a Nozzle](https://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/336L/Fluidhtml/node198.html) equation 14.75